# Entity Framework 6 update existing record with another record's values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

I use EF database-first model in my app. It's WPF MVVM app, so i use long-living DbContext, which is created when app starts and disposed when it finishes.

There are two tables - `clients` and `settings`. `settings` stores all client's settings with `client_id` as a foreign key and `settings_id` as primary key. 
In this `settings` table I have some 'default' record with `settings_id=1`and `client_id=1`. I want my app to restore 'default' settings for a client by pressing a button.

In my vewmodel i have an `ObservableCollection` of type `Client`, which is my db entity model class, and a property `SelectedClient` of type `Client`, bound to currently selected client (in some ListBox). Also i have entity class `Settings`, which has some fields representing different settings from a settings table. I want all these settings from 'default' record to replace currently selected client's settings.

So what am i doing:

```
public void OnResetClientSettingsCommandExecute()
    {
        var defaultSettings = Global.DbContext.Settings.FirstOrDefault(c => c.client_id == 1);
        if (defaultSettings == null) return;

        var tmp = defaultSettings; 
        tmp.client_id = SelectedClient.client_id; // doing this to change the only field which needs to remain untouched            
        var selectedClientSettings = Global.DbContext.Settings.FirstOrDefault(c => c.client_id == SelectedClient.client_id);
        selectedClientSettings = tmp;

        Global.DbContext.SaveChanges();

    }
```

This code doesn't work at all. The only thing i get here - is changing `client_id` for my 'default' record in `settings` to `SelectedClient`s client_id. I don't know why it happens, i thought if i would use `tmp` it'll be ok, but no. 
I know there are some practices of using `Attach()` methods or changing entity's `State` to `Modified` - i tried all of them and no one worked for me, i suppose because i use long-living DbContext approach.

Honestly, i am very confused of updating records in my app in general - i just can't do it, DbContext.SaveChanges() method does not save changes to database, but rolls them back for some reason. So i have to use raw SQL-queries, which is a bit of stone age.

Please someone help me to figure out what i am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You want to create another line in your database with default settings values and linked to the selected client id right ?

Comment: no, i already have a line, i want to replace all it's fields by the default one's, except of client_id field

Comment: As you should have noticed, you can't do it the way you do. `var tmp = defaultSettings;` won't create a new object, it will only create a new reference to already existing object.

Comment: that's why i asked a question - I realize that my code is completely wrong :)

Comment: If you want to update selectedClientSettings then update its value one by one. Or you should consider using AutoMapper.

Comment: Show me the `Settings` entity and I will elaborate an answer

Comment: public partial class Setting
    {
        public int settings_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> client_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> write_delay { get; set; }
        public string serviceName { get; set; } }     -- etc. (there are about 20 more fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a class with method like this

```
public static void CopyValues<T>(T source, T destination)
{
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach(var prop in props)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(source);
        prop.SetValue(destination, value);
    }
}
```

Then assign your keys to temporary variables, copy the rest of the properties and reassign your keys back to their original values.

```
int id = selectedClientSettings.client_id;
ObjectCopier.CopyValues<Client>(defaultSettings, selectedClientSettings);
selectedClientSettings.client_id = id;
```

Comment: That's exactly what ive been looking for, but for now it raises an exceptiopn, because it tries to copy primary key. how can i modify this to skip copying a primary key `settings_id` from default settings to selected client settings?

Comment: If you can find your primary key property programmatically, you could add some logic inside the foreach loop to skip that property.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it. But it's exhausting !

```
public void OnResetClientSettingsCommandExecute()
{
    var defaultSettings = Global.DbContext.Settings.FirstOrDefault(c => c.client_id == 1);
    if (defaultSettings == null) return;

    var selectedClientSettings = Global.DbContext.Settings.FirstOrDefault(c => c.client_id == SelectedClient.client_id);
    selectedClientSettings.serviceName = defaultSettings.serviceName;
    selectedClientSettings.write_delay = defaultSettings.write_delay;
    // etc...

    Global.DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

You should consider using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), it could be easier to write.